# Finite automata and languages question

Tags: formal-languages, automata

[image: question]

I have attempted these few simple questions, can someone let me know if this is correct please? If not please provide the answer as I learn better that way and if possible explain.

i) FA1 Start = -X1 and FA1 End = +X2

FA2 Start = -Y1 and FA2 End = +Y3

ii) FA1 NOT ACCEPTED and FA2 ACCEPTED

iii) In FA1 the string must begin with 'a' and this is in a loop, the next string is a 'b' followed by another 'b' in a loop. it can then go back round through 'a' and start again but must end with a 'b'

In FA2 it must start with a 'b' and is in a loop, then it is followed by an 'a' and go back through 'b' or continue onto 'a' and then end or go through 'a' in a loop or start the cycle again through 'b' back to the start but must end with an 'a' at y3.

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right. Here's a **hint**:

- What are the necessary suffixes for $L_1$ and $L_2$?
- Suppose $w_1 \in L_1$. Does $\mathtt{a}w_1$ or $\mathtt{b}w_1$ belong to $L_1$?
- Suppose $w_2 \in L_2$. Does $\mathtt{a}w_2$ or $\mathtt{b}w_2$ belong to $L_2$?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Is this for part iii? i dont understand what that means

Comment: The first part depends on notation you are using, but I guess it's ok. My hint regards the second and the third points; this question is rather easy, so my intention was to point you in the right direction, and not to answer your question completely. For any questions regarding the site, ask on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your answers:
(i) is OK
(ii) There are four questions, you need to give four answers.
(iii) **Hint**. Give a regular expression for the languages accepted by $FA_1$ and $FA_2$ and then convert them to plain English.